# Algorithm to compute nth root (radical) $\sqrt[n]{p(X)}$ of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, radicals

I am making a symbolic computation library which supports symbolic polynomials (both univariate and multivariate) and among other things I would like to support (possibly truncated) nth root (radical) computation of a (univariate or multivariate) polynomial since this computation is needed for some other things.

So lets say we have a polynomial $p(X) = \sum_{i}{a_{i}X^{i}}$ and I need an algorithm for $\sqrt[n]{p(X)}$.

I have found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324385/algorithm-for-finding-the-square-root-of-a-polynomial) on computing the square root of a polynomial but I dont quite get it but also I would like an algorithm for  nth root.

Library can compute all primitive operations of polynomials (both univariate and multivariate) on a general ring of coeffcients (ie add/sub/mul/div/mod/pow/derivative). (For reference [library is on github](https://github.com/foo123/Abacus))

Please provide a step-by-step algorithm in your answer or a link to such algorithm so I can test it.

PS. I tried using a variant of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) for computing nth root and adapted it to polynomial operations but result is completely off, not even close.

Note: If polynomial is not a perfect nth power then a truncated power series can be computed up to some limit (eg truncated Taylor series) as an approximation. For example the [square root algorithm on PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/SquareRootOfPolynomial) computes the Taylor series if poly is not perfect power of 2.

if poly is not a perfect nth power or power series approximation cannot be computed is fine for me if algorithm throws an error.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that in general the $n^{th}$ root does not simplify ? What do you call a *truncated* root ? What would be $\sqrt{x+1}$ ??

Comment: Yes of course, if poly is not a perfect nth power, then a truncated power series (up to some imit) can be computed (ie the Taylor series truncated)

Comment: What would be $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, of cousre a non perfect nth power can be only approximated up to some limit (eg truincated taylor series is fine for me)

Comment: What would be $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, again a truncated taylor expansion (up to some limit) is fine for my needs

Comment: What is the Taylor series for $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust, then in that case algorithm can throw an error I dont mind as long as I can compute perfect powers and approximations (truncated taylor series) and ignore those that do not have one

Comment: The square root algorithm generalizes to $n^{th}$ root. For the case of the exact root, the degree must be a multiple of $n$. You take the $n^{th}$ root of the leading term and subtract its $n^{th}$ power from the polynomial. Then cancel the next term with a second power if you can, and subtract the binomial to the $n^{th}$...

Comment: For Taylor, it may be better to take the constant term apart and develop $\sqrt[n]{p_0+x q(x)}$ using the scalar formula.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, can you expand your comment into an answer with an algorithm. I am aware that the square root algorithm readily generalises to nth root, however I have trouble understanding it correctly, so that is why I am asking for a step-by-step guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to decipher the **square root algorithm** referenced in the question and **generalise it to n-th root algorithm**.

**Algorithm: Compute nth root/radical of polynomial $p(X) = \sum_{i}a_iX^i$**

*Preliminary:* Arrange the polynomial from lowest degree term up to highest degree term or if multivariate do same according to some [monomial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) (eg LEX). $LT(p(X))$ refers to the **leading term** according to monomial order and $TT(p(X))$ refers to the **tail / last term** according to monomial order. Algorithm works both if **LT** is used instead of **TT** below but with **TT** power series approximation (if $p(X)$ is not a perfect nth power) is easier to compute up to any desired accuracy. $maxdeg(p(X))$ refers to maximum power that exists in $p(X)$ in any variable (if multivariate). $maxterms$ is a user-defined limit and refers to maximum amount of terms to be computed if a power series approximation is the result. Eg up to $6$ terms of Taylor series expansion (if possible).

- Check: If $p(X)=0$ or $p(X)=1$ return $p(X)$
- Init: $i \leftarrow 0, nterms \leftarrow 0, \text{ } r_{i}(X) \leftarrow \sqrt[n]{TT(p(X))}$
- Step 1: if $nterms \geq maxterms$ return $r_{i}(X)$ else goto to Step 2
- Step 2: $d_{i}(X) \leftarrow p(X)-r_{i}(X)^{n}$
- step 3: if $d_{i}(X)=0$ return $r_{i}(X)$ else goto to Step 4
- Step 4: $q_{i}(X) \leftarrow TT(d_{i}(X)) \text{ }/\text{ } TT(nr_{i}(X)^{n-1})$
- Step 5: if $q_{i}(X)=0$ return $r_{i}(X)$ else goto to Step 6
- Step 6: $r_{i+1}(X) \leftarrow r_{i}(X) + q_{i}(X)$
- Step 7: if $n \cdot maxdeg(r_{i+1}(X)) > maxdeg(p(X))$ this means that $p(X)$ is not a perfect nth power and that a power series approximation is being computed. $nterms \leftarrow nterms+1$
- Step 8: set $i \leftarrow i+1$ and goto Step 1

*Optionally* one can normalise returned $r(X)$ to have positive leading term coefficient if $n$ is a multiple of $2$, since in that case both $r(X)$ and $-r(X)$ are roots.

[My library](https://github.com/foo123/Abacus) is updated on github to use the above algorithm for computing nth radicals of polynomials.

Above algorithm **correctly passes the example tests**:

$p \in Q[x]$

$\sqrt{x^2} = x$

$\sqrt{(x^2)^2} = x^2$

$\sqrt[5]{(x+1)^5} = x+1$

$\sqrt{9x^4+6x^3-11x^2-4x+4} = -3x^2-x+2$

$\sqrt{x+1}=\frac{7}{256}x^5-\frac{5}{128}x^4+\frac{1}{16}x^3-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+1$ (truncated Taylor series up to `maxterms`)

$p \in Q[x, y]$

$\sqrt{4x^2-12xy+9y^2} = -2x+3y$

Comment: I guess there is an error in step 6, because as for now $r_i(X)$ will remain a zero degree polynomial.

Comment: @Lehs it has been tested and it works. If you find an error let me know.

Comment: @Lehs TT takes the whole monomial term not only the coefficient of the monomial

Comment: Aha! That explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion:**

Write $p(x)$ as $p_0(x)(1+x\,q(x))$ and compute

$$\sqrt[n]{p(x)}=\sqrt[n]{p_0(x)}\sum_{k=0}^d\binom{1/n}kx^k(q(x))^k.$$

You don't need to fully compute the powers of $q$, you can stop at the highest power that does not exceed $d-k$.

Comment: what is $d$? the degree of the polynomial? If so what about multivariate polys, which degree whould be used? is there a computationaly more efficient method (ie one that generalises the square root algorithm)?

Comment: @NikosM.: what makes you think that this is inefficient ?

Comment: I would not like to compute binomial coefiicients all the time. Also $1/n$ would be a rational and my binomial routines only work with (big) integers.

Comment: Ok I missed $q(x)$ from above.

Comment: Is it possible to generalise the square root algorthm that uses primitive operations only (and roots of coefficients and monomials)? I have those already. If you can do that I can accept the answer

Comment: @NikosM.: computing those binomial coefficients is nothing compare to the whole workload. They are fractions.

Comment: Polynomial operations and powers of polynomials indeed use much computing power (although algorithms are optimised), yet I feel although the formula is correct that the binomial coeffs can be avoided or maybe computed recursively with only one operation per iteration. Still I am looking for a generalisation of square root algorithm but with step-by-step explanation as the references I have found (included in the question) are unclear to me.

Comment: I just noticed that the formula gives $0$ for the square root $p(x)=x^2$ as $p_0$ is zero

Comment: @NikosM.: of course.

Comment: I managed to understand the square root / long division algorithm and also generalise it to k-th root, see my answer